# Allow Site Access Only Through Redirect IIS MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have researched this and only found solutions for protecting images or certain pages from direct URL access; however, I would like to know how to restrict access to an entire site, allowing access only through a redirect from another site. 
Our site is ASP.NET served through IIS 7.

Comment: Every HTTP request has a header that contains the URL that this request originated. For ASP.NET is `Request.UrlReferrer`. You can check this property and allow or deny access to your website. Note that this is not a full-proof solution, since this header can be faked or browsers might omit adding this property.

Comment: Are both sites on the same web server. What is the use-case for this scenario?

Comment: They are on different servers. We have a Portal site and a Reporting site. We would like to force users to enter the reporting site only by going through the portal site.